# JavaScript (VueJS) reload list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get data out of two databases, compare/filter them and load them into a list:

```
<b-list-group v-if="items">
  <test-item
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item._id"
      :item="item"
      @updated="fetchData()"
  ></test-item>
</b-list-group>
```

When I add data to items, the list won't reload. Also I got a search-field:

```
   <b-form-input v-model="search" placeholder="Search for..."></b-form-input>
```

**How can I call a method and reload the list, if someone is entering data into the search-field?**

And what is **@updated** doing actually? I used google so many times. And I wouldn't ask here, if I didn't try for many hours to understand whats happening.

So what might be the problem ?

Comment: We need to see some more Code. What is fetchData? Where are you filtering?

Comment: fetchData() just loads the entrys of (let's say) DB1 on items. So i want to filter item's with some attributes, but in DB1 are just "the ID's" of those attributes. I need to look in DB2 to find the related names and filter them. The filter-method is written and correct, it loads the right entrys on items. But it did not get called, thats the problem actually. I need some trigger when search got changed, so the method filterItems (which loads the right items on items) get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example from vuejs docs, where they use watcher for v-model. I think you need to have a watcher for search model and can reload the list.

(Source link) ==> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html?#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed

```
<div id="debounce-search-demo">
  <input v-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Type something">
  <strong>{{ searchIndicator }}</strong>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#debounce-search-demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    searchQueryIsDirty: false,
    isCalculating: false
  },
  computed: {
    searchIndicator: function () {
      if (this.isCalculating) {
        return '⟳ Fetching new results'
      } else if (this.searchQueryIsDirty) {
        return '... Typing'
      } else {
        return '✓ Done'
      }
    }
  },
  watch: {
    searchQuery: function () {
      this.searchQueryIsDirty = true
      this.expensiveOperation()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // This is where the debounce actually belongs.
    expensiveOperation: _.debounce(function () {
      this.isCalculating = true
      setTimeout(function () {
        this.isCalculating = false
        this.searchQueryIsDirty = false
      }.bind(this), 1000)
    }, 500)
  }
})
```